# MYSQL - getting records not in another table through a relationship

Tags: mysql

I have four tables:

1) categories

```
id   |  name
------------------
1    |  category 1
2    |  category 2
3    |  category 3
4    |  category 4
5    |  category 5
6    |  category 6
```

2) countries

```
id   |  name
------------------
1    |  country 1
2    |  country 2
3    |  country 3
4    |  country 4
5    |  country 5
6    |  country 6
```

3) users

```
id   |  name       | country_id
-------------------------------
1    |  john doe 1 | 1
2    |  john doe 2 | 2
3    |  john doe 3 | 3
4    |  john doe 4 | 4
5    |  john doe 5 | 4
6    |  john doe 6 | 5
```

4) users_categories

```
id   |  category_id | user_id
------------------------------
1    |  1           |2
2    |  1           |3
3    |  2           |4
```

What i need to know is what categories don't have any user in some country.

My starting point was getting the categories with no users, but i'm stucked on getting the list by country..

```
 SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM users_categories);
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but something like this might work with $country_id being the id of the country.

```
select c.*
from categories c
left join users_categories uc on c.id = uc.category_id
left join users u on u.id = uc.user_id and u.country_id = $country_id
where 
u.id is null
group by 
c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this also

```
select categories.*,user.*, country.*  from users as user 
leftjoin country as country on country.id = user.country_id
leftjoin users_categories as users_categories on users_categories.user_id =  user.id
leftjoin categories as categories on categories.id = users_categories.category_id 
where user.id is null;
```

Comment: Thank you. It returns 0 results i think we are missing something

Comment: yes all the user has country  thats way it is return zero

Comment: True, but categories 3,4,5 and 6 are not assigned to any user, so at least the output should be categories 3,4,5 and 6 in all countries

Comment: where user.id not in(2,3,4);     you can try this